# Email from apex class not delivered

Tags: apex, visualforce, email

I am trying to send email from an apex class. My code runs without error. but  email is not delivered. This is my visual force page :

```
 <apex:form styleClass="form1" >    
       <apex:outputPanel id="loginform" styleClass="thumbnail center well well-small text-center " >
            <h6>Password help: </h6><br />
            <div class="input-prepend">
               <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-envelope"></i></span>
               <apex:inputText required="true" id="username" styleClass="form-control" value="{!emailText}"/>
            </div><br/>

           <apex:commandButton styleClass="btn"  action="{!sendCustomEmail}" value="Reset Password" />
           <div >
               <apex:outputText styleClass="alert-success" value="{!response}"></apex:outputText>
           </div>


        </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:form>
```

and this is my function in the controller:

```
public PageReference sendCustomEmail(){
    if(!checkInputValid(emailText, EMAIL_ERROR)) { return null; }
    Contact [] lstContacts = [select Id, Email, password__c from Contact where Email = :emailText ];

    if(!checkContactFound(lstContacts)) { return null; } 

    // Define the email
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage(); 
    // generate a randome string
    String code = generateRandomString(20);

    mail.setToAddresses(new String[] {emailText});
    mail.setReplyTo('noreply@reftrans.com');
    mail.setSenderDisplayName('Refugee Transitions');
    mail.setSubject('You have requested password reset');
    mail.setPlainTextBody('click here www.google.com ');
    try{
        Messaging.SendEmailResult[] resultMail = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
        if(resultMail[0].isSuccess()){       
            response = 'Password reset Link has been sent to you email !!';
            emailText = '';
        }else{
            response = resultMail[0].getErrors().get(0).getMessage();
        }
    }catch(System.EmailException ex){
        response = ex.getMessage();
    }   


    return null;
}
```

I have checked the deliverable setting in email --> which is properly set to all emails. I am not sure what to look for next.

Comment: Time to look at the debug legs and see what is going on in your code.  I would assume one of your conditions is not being met. Also, debug response in your catch block and see if anything show up.....

Comment: Hey Thanks @Eric for the response, I got the email delivered when i accessed the page through site , when i was trying to fill the form in preview mode it was not working. I still dont understand why though.  I have requested the email logs and My response was always a success even in preview mode.